# share images to facebook from rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

Tried researching this for a long time, but really not understanding the facebook API. Only thing I've been able to successfully link to is the root of the site.

**Here's the issue:**
I have a site with user profiles. 
User profiles each have a number of images that were uploaded by users. 
I'd like to give users the ability to share these INDIVIDUAL images to facebook directly from their profile. It would also be great if some of the info below the image would populate the share dialogue.

Probably way off, but below is one of the solutions I tried. However, the open graph info in header took over when attempting to share. Ultimately, what I'd like is for the link to lead back to the user profile at the anchor point of the 'log' record. Let me know if this is possible. About ready to give up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 const harvests = JSON.parse(gon.harvests);
 for (var i = 0; i < harvests.length; i++) {
   var logItem = harvests[i];
   var baseURL = 'https://www.example.com/users/';

  $(`#log-${logItem.id} .share`).on('click', function() {
     FB.ui({
       method: 'share',
       display: 'popup',
       href: baseURL + logItem.user.id + '#log-' + `${logItem.id}`
     }), function(response){});
   });
 };
});
```

Comment: Update: My mistake! My past solution does in fact lead to the correct user page from facebook. However, the preview image and information is being grabbed from the header. I'm hoping the generated image is a preview of the individual log.

Comment: The image is taken from the og:image meta tag(s) of the shared URL. If you want to share individual pieces of content, then you should also have individual URLs for them.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Would you recommend I create individual URLs for each resource but then forward users to the anchor tag on the user profile page where all items are displayed?